# Spark Core is Not taking More than 530 MB For Executors

Tags: apache-spark

We are running spark in cluster mode. As per spark documentation we can provide spark.executor.memory = 3g to change the executor memory size. or we can provide spark-shell --executor-memory 3g. But both the ways when i go and check in spark UI it is showing each executor having 530 MB of memory. Any ideas how to change the memory more than 530MB.

Comment: Check environment page of spark UI?

Comment: Which cluster are you running on? If Yarn, please specify `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` value. Also, from which column in the UI is showing 530MB?

Comment: Add you full command call please

Comment: Thanks, Yes i'm running in Yarn -cluster mode. In UI "Storage Memory" column shows 530 MB.

Comment: Full Command : /usr/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-client --num-executors 5 --driver-memory 4g  --executor-memory 1g --class com.test.execute --files /tmp/log4j.properties execute.jar